# Finding a sub array in an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to write a program using two methods that determines if a sub array is located within an array. subArray() is supposed to receive two arrays and return the index of the start of the sub array within the array. If the sub array is not located in the array it returns -1. subArray() then calls subArrayAppearsAt() and passes in the two arrays and a location. subArrayAppearsAt() is supposed to return true if the sub array is located in the array starting at the location passed in, false otherwise. 
Currently if I pass in array {1,2,3} and sub array {2,3}, it returns 2 as the starting position but it should return 1.
If I pass in array {1,2,3,4,5} and sub array {4}, it returns -1, but it should return 3.
Does anyone see why this might be happening?

```
        public static int subArray(int [ ] array, int [ ] subArray )
           {
            boolean result=true;
            int subArrayLength = subArray.length;

        if (subArrayLength == 0) {
            return -1;
        }

        int limit = array.length - subArrayLength;
        int i;
        for ( i = 0; i <= limit; i++)
            result = subArrayAppearsAt(array, subArray, i );

        if (result==true)
            return i;
        else
            return -1;

    }


    public static boolean subArrayAppearsAt(int[] largeArray, int[] subArray, int i) {

        {
            if (subArray[0] == largeArray[i]) 
            {
            boolean subArrayFound = true;

            for (int j = 1; j < subArray.length; j++) 
            {
                if (subArray[j] != largeArray[i+j]) 
                {
                    subArrayFound = false;
                    j=subArray.length;
                }

                /* Sub array found - return its index */
                if (subArrayFound==true) 
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /* Return default value */
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this part

```
for ( i = 0; i <= limit; i++)
    result = subArrayAppearsAt(array, subArray, i );
```

it sets result every time it goes through the loop. If you test if  `{4}` is conatined in `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` it will set `result` to the return value of `subArrayAppearsAt(array, subArray, 4);` which will return false

So for that problem you could do something like

```
for ( i = 0; i <= limit; i++) {
    result = subArrayAppearsAt(array, subArray, i );

    if (result==true)
        return i;
}
return -1;
```

The other problem is, that `i` will be incremented after it goes into the for-loop the last time, and then you return that value. That problem should be solved with my code solution too.

I didn't test my solution but it should work ;)

**EDIT**

Sorry that wasn't all correct. Your `subArrayAppearsAt()` returns true too early. Edit your `subArrayAppearsAt()` function to this and it should work

```
public static boolean subArrayAppearsAt(int[] largeArray, int[] subArray, int i)
{
    if (subArray[0] == largeArray[i])
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < subArray.length; j++)
        {
            if (subArray[j] != largeArray[i+j])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you want to know the start position you should put the *if* that checks the *result* inside de *loop*

```
        public static int subArray(int [ ] array, int [ ] subArray )
           {
            boolean result=true;
            int subArrayLength = subArray.length;

        if (subArrayLength == 0) {
            return -1;
        }

        int limit = array.length - subArrayLength;
        int i;
        for ( i = 0; i <= limit; i++){
            result = subArrayAppearsAt(array, subArray, i );

            if (result==true)
              return i;
        }



            return -1;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] first = {1,2,4,5,3,2,1,3,4,5,6,33,432,21,5};
    int[] second = {2,1};

    System.out.println(findpos(first, second));
}

private static int findpos(int[] a, int[] b){
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        if(a[i]!=b[0]){
            continue;
        }
        if(a.length - i < b.length) return -1;

        int itemp = i;
        boolean found = true;
        for(int j=0; j<b.length; j++){
            if(itemp < a.length && a[itemp]!=b[j]){
                found = false;
            }
            itemp++;
        }
        if(found){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```